# PostgreSQL error : Must be owner of schema public

Tags: database, postgresql, prisma

I am using Prisma 2 as interface with postgres db. I want to reset the db, however, when I try, I get the error:

```
✕ Resetting the database has failed with an error from the database: 
✕ Error: Invalid `prisma.executeRaw()` invocation:
Raw query failed. Code: `42501`. Message: `db error: ERROR: must be owner of schema public`
```

The postgres role I created, `aim`, for the same named db has the following permissions:

```
 Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 aim  | Create role, Create DB                                     | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

I created a user by the same name in Ubuntu OS so I can connect to the db.

As per my understanding, the above error is because I do not have the permissions to alter or delete the db ``?

How would I go about fixing this. The commands from this [link](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-drop-database/) didn't delete the db `aim` either whether I was logged in as `postges` or `aim` role.

Comment: The error message is unambiguous: your tool is trying to do something with the `public` schema it has no permission to do, perhaps `DROP`. Log statements to gain certainty.

Comment: I would suggest trying with a user in Postgres that has full permission of the DB and then narrow down the issue.